# Returning values from different rows in a stored procedure as different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure:

```
`SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER    PROCEDURE [ebs].[DB_Task_ONEYCRPRaport]
    --@startDate      DATE,
    --@endDate      DATE 
    
AS
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT
CAST(A.ExternalMerchantId as varchar) "Merchant_guid", -- ok
CAST(C.CreatedOn AS DATE) "Purchase_date", --ok
CAST(C.CreatedOn AS TIME) "Purchase_hour", --ok
C.ContractNo "Funding_reference",--ok
APP.OrderNo "External_reference", --ok
A.CustomerInternalId "Customer_external_code",--ok
CASE WHEN I.TotalAmountToPay = 0 THEN '-' ELSE '+' END "Total_amount_symbol",--ok
CASE WHEN I.TotalAmountToPay = 0 THEN I.TotalAmountToRecover ELSE I.TotalAmountToPay END "Total_amount"
from ebs.Account as A
JOIN ebs.FTOS_CB_Contract AS C ON A.Accountid = C.CustomerId
JOIN ebs.FTOS_CB_BankAccount AS BA ON BA.FTOS_CB_BankAccountid = C.MainBankAccountId
JOIN ebs.FTOS_CB_BankAccountOperation AS BAO ON BAO.BankAccountId = BA.FTOS_CB_BankAccountid
JOIN Ebs.FTOS_CMB_Currency AS CU ON CU.FTOS_CMB_Currencyid = C.CurrencyId
JOIN ebs.FTOS_TPM_Invoice AS I ON I.BankAccountId = BA.FTOS_CB_BankAccountid
JOIN ebs.FTOS_TPM_InvoiceDetail AS ID ON ID.InvoiceId = I.FTOS_TPM_Invoiceid
JOIN ebs.FTOS_BNKAP_Application AS APP ON APP.ContractId = ID.ContractId 
JOIN ebs.FTOS_CB_Payment AS P ON I.FTOS_TPM_Invoiceid=P.InvoiceId
JOIN ebs.FTOS_BP_BankingProduct AS BP ON BP.FTOS_BP_BankingProductid=(SELECT CO.ProductId from ebs.FTOS_CB_Contract AS CO where CO.FTOS_CB_Contractid = ID.ContractId)
JOIN ebs.FTOS_TPM_PreInvoiceDetail AS PID ON PID.ContractId = C.FTOS_CB_Contractid
left JOIN ebs.FTOS_ONEY_ICE_Repayment as R ON P.PaymentNo = R.PaymentNo
left JOIN ebs.FTOS_ONEY_ICE_Repayment_Details AS RD ON RD.FTOS_ONEY_ICE_Repaymentid = R.FTOS_ONEY_ICE_Repaymentid -- detalii plati efectuate
left JOIN ebs.FTOS_ONEY_ICE_Libra_ReceivedPayments AS RP ON RP.FTOS_CB_Contractid = C.FTOS_CB_Contractid --and DATEPART(week, C.CreatedOn) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) take current week results

END`
```

I have another table where commissions are stored, the problem is I don't know how to select them in my stored procedure if they are on separate columns:

[image]

Here is the test query:

```
SELECT PID.*
FROM [ebs].[FTOS_TPM_PreInvoiceDetail] as PID
WHERE PID.Name = 'name'
```

Basically for this example I want those values 20 and 5 to be selected in my stored procedures as two different values, how can I achieve that?

I tried created another stored procedure, but I think is a very bad idea.

Comment: I can't say I follow what you are asking here. Why can't you `JOIN` to the `Commission` table based on  it's `id`?

Comment: I tried, but it will get me only the first value found there. In my case(the photo), the calculated value of 20

Comment: It sounds like they want to pivot the data held in different rows into values held in multiple columns within the same output row.

Comment: *"I tried, but it will get me only the first value found there"* That isn't how a `JOIN` works. If you have 1 row related to 2 rows, you will get 2 rows back, not 1.

Comment: Some *consumable* sample data (not an image) and expected results will likely help us help you here.

Comment: What I meant by that is, if I try for example 'SELECT PID.commissionValue "comm1" ', then I can't use ' SELECT PID.commissionValue "comm2"'.

Comment: How many different commision values could you have?  Is it always two, or could theyre be 50+?  Why do they need to be in their own columns?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: They are a maximum of 3, basically I have CommissionId, which state the type of commission, each of these commission are applied to a contract, what I want is to select all these 2/3 commissions inside my procedures

Comment: If the `CommissionId` values are the same across all contracts, you can use conditional aggregation (i.e. `sum(case when CommissionId = 'Id1' then CalculatedValue else 0 end) as Commission1Value` etc), but if they differ, you will need to `pivot` the commission data (either using the `pivot` statement or via other means) before joining onto your main dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that will work